# Having an output of all 0.00 float values no matter what number values are being inputted

Tags: c

This code is supposed to print out the exact values of what is being inputted with 2 decimal places, yet it only prints out all 0.00 regardless of what numbers are being inputted. Surprisingly the names are printing out perfectly, but the (Ordered amount) values printed will always be zero with 2 decimal places .Can anyone please tell me what went wrong?? And yes I am still a beginner at this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct customer
{   char customer_name[20];
    float order_amount;
}c[10];

int main()
{   int i;

    clrscr();

    printf("\n******Enter customer details******\n");

    for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        printf("\nEnter customer name: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(c[i].customer_name);
        printf("Enter order amount: ");
        scanf(" %0.2f",&c[i].order_amount);
    }

    printf("\n\t*********Displaying information*********\n");
    printf("\nCustomers that has ordered are: \n");

    for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {   printf("\nCustomer name: %s\n",c[i].customer_name);     
        printf("Ordered amount: %0.2f\n",c[i].order_amount);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `gets()`. Ever. Buffer overflows will haunt you.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes *undefined behavior* and `gets()`, has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and removed from C11. Wild code...

Comment: Would you mind posting your input data used for testing?

Comment: But then i tried to use scanf, and it ends up skipping the second input of names, so i switched to gets with fflush, and miraculously it worked fine. Oh and even after adding space before the %s like:

Comment: scanf(" %s",&c[i].customer_name) still wont work, i dont know why but it just skips the process and doesnt allow a second input of names.

Comment: The input data for testing are just 10 random short names like Mike, Jack, Max, Lee, etc. And all values inputted are all random 3 digit numbers(its a habit O_O) like 500, 300, 200, 499,812, etc. All random.

Comment: `%0.2f` is not a valid conversion-specifier for `scanf()` as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a whitespace in scanf. Should be scanf("%s",...) and as well scanf("%f",...) not scanf(" %s", ....) neither scanf(" %f",...)

Answer (score 1):

First, performing `scanf` with a format does not work properly. Not sure of what it does, but it's utterly useless to read a float. Just use `%f`, no space, and the float will be read.

Had you checked `scanf` return code, you'd have seen that it returned 0 instead of 1.

Then, drop `gets` in favor of protected `scanf` to avoid buffer overflow.

That code below works fine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct customer
{   char customer_name[20];
    float order_amount;
}c[10];

int main()
{   int i;
    int n=10;       

    printf("\n******Enter customer details******\n");

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter customer name: ");
        scanf("%19s",c[i].customer_name);  // not above 19 characters
        printf("Enter order amount: ");        
        scanf("%f",&(c[i].order_amount)); // plain scanf %f
    }
    // print routine is unchanged

    printf("\n\t*********Displaying information*********\n");
    printf("\nCustomers that has ordered are: \n");

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {   printf("\nCustomer name: %s\n",c[i].customer_name);     
        printf("Ordered amount: %0.2f\n",c[i].order_amount);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: when? when compiling? which line? please be more specific. Works here on gcc